# Как react компоненты работают с html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Как писать react компоненты, если они есть многостраничный сайт, и при переходи по url приходит html страница, а не json данные? Т.е. во всех мануалах, используется метод renderComponent, который к переданному элементу root добавляет переданный jsx, и в дальнейшем при изменение состояния перерисовывает этот jsx. А в случае с html  у меня же уже  отрисован этот элемент, и мне изначально его перерисовывать не нужно, а нужно перерисовывать его только после какого нибудь события, например нажатия на кнопку. Как тогда использовать react?

Comment: Тупо кусок который надо перерисовать целиком и не трогать? Тогда просто компонент-обертка с __dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Перерисовать надо умно и кучу всего делать? Тогда для реального приложения это порой сложная эпическая история, гуглить по словам isomorphic app и ssr. Тут например https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.md

Comment: @Утка Учится Уму , Спасибо. Но не совсем понял как в моём случае пользоваться "огда просто компонент-обертка с __dangerouslySetInnerHTML"?(я просто пока не очень хорошо разобрался в react). Просто во всех обучалках показывают примеры для однастраничных приложений, где с сервера приходят только данные, а не html, а в моём случае обычный сайт, и приходит html страница. Не подскажите, нет ли мануалов или статеек где работа идёт с обычным сайтом?

Comment: Смотрите, смысл в том, хотите ли Вы работать с тем html что пришел как с полноценным реактовским компонентом (в общем случае большая и сложная история), либо просто скормить как есть куску приложения и не трогать. Если скормить как есть - так это по сути просто  .innerHTML. Вот просто .innerHTML в реакте есть: (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)